# UITableView - Data fault when accessing object

Tags: xcode, core-data

I'm using Core Data in a project which contains five items in the navigation bar each belonging to a separate navigation controller. Each items got the following structure:

```
Item1NavController » Item1RootTableView > Item1RootDetailView
```

After using the application for a while (like changing the items in the navigation bar, loading the detail view and so on) I've got the problem, that the rootTableView returns a selected object as a fault and causing the detail view to crash.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Getting object in table view and load detail view
    _contact = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    ContactDetailVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactDetailVC"];
    vc.contact = _contact;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactDetailVC animated:YES];
}
```

The log shows the following message:

```
 Selected contact: <Contact: 0x1f5e9d10> (entity: Contact; id: 0x1f5b38d0 <x-coredata://0F273F3F-708F-417F-915B-AE9EBB3133C0/Contact/p3828> ; data: <fault>)

 // Error message
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSObjectID_64_1 matchcode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x213b4e20'
```

After reading into the docs about faulting in Core Data this behavior seems to be normal on the one hand. But on the other hand Core Data should automatically refetch the object when I'm accessing it?

Thanks for any ideas!

**Update**

When I'm refetching with the NSFetchedResultsController every time the view appears the problem doesn't appear.

**Update II**

```
@class Contact;
//...
@property (strong, nonatomic) Contact *contact;
```

Comment: What about contact property? Do you retain it? Are you using ARC or not?

Comment: I'm using ARC in this project.

Comment: Seeing fault in the logs is normal. What crash are you getting?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304257/coredata-error-data-fault/7304350#7304350

Comment: Updated my answer. "matchcode" is a value in the NSManagedObject "Contact" that I'm accessing. So the data seems be arrive in the detail view as a fault as well.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the `matchcode` attribute is not mapped properly in your model or your managed object subclass (both `.h` and the `@dynamic` declaration in `.m`). Double check that the name of this attribute is correct (maybe `@"matchCode"`?) and that you are also trying to access it with the correct name. Check that your `_contact` variable and the attribute of your detail view controller are of the correct type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the matchcode attribute is not mapped properly, why should it work to access it a few times before Core Data is turning the object into a fault? Checked the model and managed object subclass - everything seems to be right.

Comment: Then it is the _contact variable or the attribute in your detail view controller.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the implementation of my contact object in the detail view. Can't determine where the problem is.