# Get fault when iterate through a fetched request data from Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coredata Error “data: <fault>”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304257/coredata-error-data-fault)

I try to iterate through a data fetched from SQLite database using Core data. I store all fetched data from CoreData in `NSMutableArray`. When I iterate using for loop in this array only I can get first element in the array but the rest of element get me this error:

```
<Task: 0xf18b390> (entity: Task; id: 0xf18a700 <x-coredata://7388F0B7-E583-4BF0-BE64-08AD014EC583 /Task/p104> ; data: <fault>
```

below the code I'm using:

```
dispatch_sync(classificationQueue, ^{
    NSMutableArray *waitingTasks  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self getInsepectorTaskByTaskStatus:managedObjectContext :TASKSTATUSWAITING:CLASSIFICATIONFORMTYPE]];

    for (Task *cTask in waitingTasks){
        //Here when print cTask nsmanagedobject get me fault data
        NSLog(@"BBBBBBB %@",cTask);
        corporateName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:(classificationWaitingTask.corporate.corporateTitle?classificationWaitingTask.corporate.corporateTitle:@"-")];
        [self performSelector:@selector(sendingClassificationForm:) withObject:classificationWaitingTask];
 sleep(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Comment: show the code where us getting the data and storing it in your nsmutable array

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304257/coredata-error-data-fault

Comment: Does your app crash? A fault is not an error...

Comment: Search for "Faulting and Uniquing" in the "Core Data Programming Guide" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolve occurring data :fault

```
NSFetchRequest *taskDataRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *dataEntityResultForm = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[taskDataRequest setEntity:dataEntityResultForm];
//Note: Resolove problem happen data:fault by this properites 
[taskDataRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

Comment: That is correct, but you should understand that "fault" objects are **not an error**. It is a Core Data feature to save memory.

Comment: Ok but i faced problem in another place , when i used sleep through iteration make data fault how i can resolved it

Comment: I do not understand you last comment. Which problem? What other place? Why do you use "sleep" at all?