# XMPPFramework - Message Archiving in Core Data "<data: fault>"

Tags: ios, core-data, xmpp, xmppframework

First post for me. I've searched through a lot of the questions and answers in regards to storing/archiving messages in the Core Data and I just can't seem to crack it.

I could be doing something very silly, so any help is appreciated.

Setup my stream here:

```
-(void)setupStream {
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *xmppMessageArchivingStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    XMPPMessageArchiving *xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingStorage];
    [xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];
    [xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppMessageArchivingModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}
```

Attempting to test my archiving here:

```
-(void) testMessageArchive {
    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

The issue is that I can't seem to get any sensible information from the messages object. The contents are as below. Do I need to bury down deeper to get the message text and sender? The messages array has one object in it, which is correct since I only sent one message. Item in message array is:

```
> <_PFArray 0x10f0021a0>( <XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject:
> 0x1099de1b0> (entity: XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject; id:
> 0xd000000000040000
> <x-coredata://1013D7F5-A511-45F0-B719-13EEF1DD32A3/XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject/p1>
> ; data: <fault>) )
```

Comment: Your code looks ok, so, what is the problem? You forgot to describe it

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to get any sensible information from the messages object. The contents are as above. Do I need to bury down deeper to get the message text and sender?

Comment: it is expected, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304350/1097384

Comment: No idea how I couldn't find that on a search. I'll mark this as answered when I jump on my laptop. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @RyanKil :facing the same issue as you are.were you able to solve the problem.

Comment: ha...finally soved it..forgot using NSSortDescriptor