# NSPredicate compare numbers issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have this function that supposed fetch from CoreData with Predicate:

```
- (NSArray*)fetchingManagedObjectsWithEntityName:(NSString*)entityName predicate:(NSString*)predicateFormat
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[MainDb sharedDb] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (array.count == 0)
    {
        return @[];
    }
    return array;
}
```

But for some reason it's not working fine, this is how I call it:

```
NSArray *objects = [[DownloadData sharedData] fetchingManagedObjectsWithEntityName:@"DbSomething" predicate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == %d", someId.intValue]];
```

I've tried these predicates as well:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == '%d'", someId.intValue]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == %ld", someId.integerValue]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == '%ld'", someId.integerValue]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == %@", someId]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == '%@'", someId]
```

The 'somethingId' that is in the CoreData DbSomething object is an NSNumber.

I always get a list of all the 'DbSomething' objects that looks like this, the last one is always with data, all the others are 'fault':

```
<_PFArray 0x1700368c0>(
<DbSomething: 0x1702db890> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd0000000005c0012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p23> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702db9e0> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000000c00012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p48> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702db900> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000001280012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p74> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702db970> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd0000000019c0012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p103> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702db740> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000002340012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p141> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702d9830> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000002980012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p166> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702db820> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000003240012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p201> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702db7b0> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000003680012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p218> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702d7d80> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000003e00012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p248> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1702d82c0> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000004740012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p285> ; data: <fault>),
<DbSomething: 0x1742cf490> (entity: DbSomething; id: 0xd000000004e40012 <x-coredata://FD3BA7EB-B2D7-4133-B209-A94C58949C2F/DbHomeDish/p313> ; data: {
    somethingId = 168;
})
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to transmit not a string for predicate, but a predicate object as parameter. Caused some trouble in my code in some cases. and `x == %d` with `.integerValue` was always working for me the best

Comment: @geo It's not working also `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"somethingId == %d", someId.integerValue]`

Comment: `- (NSArray*)fetchingManagedObjectsWithEntityName:(NSString*)entityName predicate:(NSPredicate*)p_predicate` -> `if(pPredicate) [request setPredicate:p_predicate];` just a hint to avoid some errors, maybe not the solution for this problem. That's why it's only a comment ;) and can you iterate through all entities and print their (overridden) stringValue method? Are they realy all blanks?

Comment: @geo That's the problem, they are not blanks, but showing as blanks when printing! Really weird issue..

Comment: It's nothing wrong with the objects marked as 'faults'. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304257/coredata-error-data-fault

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, but why is the `NSPredicate` return all the objects instead the only one he should return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure your predicate produced with the passed predicate string is reliable.

I would expect that `predicateWithFormat` expects a format string, so it can interpolate with the given arguments rather than having the arguments already inserted in the format string. It certainly works in a way that is different from the `NSString` method `stringWithFormat` in some cases.

E.g.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"John"]  // "name = 'John'"
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"John"]        // "name = John"
```

Do we really know what the internal representation of a predicate is? We know what string is passed to SQLite (by turning on SQLite debugging), and we know what the `description` returns, but we don't know how the predicate works internally.

Therefore, you should perhaps refactor your method to accept a predicate rather than a predicate string.

Besides, your method is hardly necessary. What it does can anyway be achieved much more succinctly.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:"Something"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", aNumber];
NSArray *result = [[MainDb sharedDb].context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Counting the additional lines of code you need when you have to construct the predicate yourself, calling your method is hardly an advantage. Note that the above will also return an empty array if there are no results.

Comment: Great answer although that wasn't my problem, the problem was that I had more than 1 object with the same ID. Thanks anyway man!