# data: <fault> issue in another function after fetching data from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios8

I'm completely new to coredata few days back i started using core data. i have written a predicate to fetch data from coredata if i log data in current method it works fine. if i log data in another method it shows "data: "

```
<Profile: 0x16451ba0> (entity: Profile; id: 0x1633c150 <x-coredata://41971DAD-4658-4C38-9D14-7FDFFA57E032/Profile/p6> ; data: <fault>)

-(void)populateCurrentUserData{

       self.blockListArray = [self dataForJid:[[DataManager sharedHandler]userToken]];
   Profile *profile = [self.blockListArray objectAtIndex:0];
          NSLog(@"Data is :%@",profile.userId);//prints nil
      NSLog(@"Data is :%@",self.blockListArray); //"<Profile: 0x17bb23f0> (entity: Profile; id: 0x17bb1fe0 <x-coredata://41971DAD-4658-4C38-9D14-7FDFFA57E032/Profile/p1> ; data: <fault>)"

 }

-(NSArray *)dataForJid:(NSString *)inJid{
   NSArray *data = [[NSArray alloc]init];
   NSError *error;
   self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   MKAUserProfileCoreData *storage = [[MKAUserProfileCoreData alloc]init];
   NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage managedObjectContext];
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription   entityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
   NSPredicate *profilePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId = %@", inJid];
   [request setPredicate:profilePredicate];
   [request setEntity:entity];
   [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
   data = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
   NSLog(@"Data is :%@",data); //This log works fine

return data;
```

}

```
/.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface MKAUserProfileCoreData : NSObject
{
 NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext   *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@end

/.m


 #import "MKAUserProfileCoreData.h"
 #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

 @implementation MKAUserProfileCoreData
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

 if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return managedObjectContext;
 }

 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
 if (coordinator != nil) {
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
}
 return managedObjectContext;
```

}

```
   - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

   if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return managedObjectModel;
  }
   managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
   return managedObjectModel;
}





  - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

  if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
  }

 NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"splashUserProfile.sqlite"]];

NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                              initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should
     not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during
     development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that
     instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

     Typical reasons for an error here include:
     * The persistent store is not accessible
     * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object
     model
     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
     */
    abort();
   }

   return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

 - (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
//NSLog(@"Path is %@", path);
return path;
 }

 @end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coredata Error "data: <fault>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304257/coredata-error-data-fault)

Comment: @Azat but that answer didn't work for me though i user [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]

Comment: @Azat What the question started asking was a duplicate of that, but since core data faults are not a problem, and this code has some sort of problem in it, as long as it is edited to reflect that, it will no longer be a duplicate.

Comment: @WillM. however I cannot cancel my flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `storage` and `moc` are created locally in `dataForJid:`.  When that method completes, both these variables will be deallocated.  Hence the NSManagedObjects become invalid.  You need to keep a strong reference to your CoreData stack - for example by making `MKAUserProfileCoreData` into a singleton, or by building the stack directly in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work fine or have any issues running? Core data faults are not bad, they are a way of saving memory. A core data fault means that the entire object has not yet been loaded into memory. However, as soon as the object is requested, it will be loaded into memory.

Comment: If i request object it is returning null

Comment: @user3252627 please edit your question to include your actual problem and more details