# Faults - core data can only acces object once when working with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

Ok, this is a weird bug I just can't figure out. I fetch expenses from a core data entity. Then I sort those results on the date. I use this sorted structure to get the correct data for the correct section and row in the tableView. This code all works and the cells in the TableView outlets are filled in correctly in cellForRowAtIndexPath. But when a cell goes out of the tableView (=queued) and later gets loaded in back again(=Dequeued), I can't access the expense and its relationship anymore... **Let me further explain: Here the core data structures**

```
extension Category {
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var catHasExpenses: NSOrderedSet? }


extension Expenses {
@NSManaged var amount: NSNumber
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var expenseHasCat: Category }
```

I fetch the data and sort it. This code still works fine, so moving on. When its sorted its of datastructure..

```
var expensesDictionary = ([(NSDate, Expenses)])() //Array of tuples
```

Then when the cells load I want to access the expenseHasCat relation. Everything works fine the first time the table loads.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("expensesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomExpensesTableViewCell    
        let pos = getPositionInDictionary(indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)

        // set Category image - imageName = expenseHasCat.name
        var expense = self.expensesDictionary[pos].1
        NSLog("\(expense)") //check printout below
        cell.expenseCategory.image = UIImage(named: (expense.expenseHasCat.name)! as String);
        return cell
    }
```

But for some reason **if the cell goes out of tableView and gets loaded back in later I can't access the expense anymore**. It says it is nil while unwrapping an optional. I can't figure out why that would be the case. The expensesDictionary has not been changed at all. I just can't figure out why it would work the first time but not the second time.

Anyone an eye on what happens here?

**Update! - fault must be the base problem...**

I just noticed that **print of the Expenses object** at self.expensesDictionary[pos].1 is a not able to fire the fault or the values are somehow nil now... First print is when it loads, second if when it can't load. Anyone an idea how I can extract the data from the fault?

```
    <x-coredata://9FBBD46A-CD75-4DAB-A796-5BA945927C9A/Expenses/p23> 
; data: {
    amount = 8;
    date = "2015-11-14 21:57:51 +0000";
    expenseHasCat = "0x7ba6a310 <x-coredata://9FBBD46A-CD75-4DAB-A796-5BA945927C9A/Category/p8>";
    name = nil;
})

(entity: Expenses; id: 0x7ba71b00
<x-coredata://9FBBD46A-CD75-4DAB-A796-5BA945927C9A/Expenses/p23> 
; data: <fault>)
```

**I did not yet find a solution**

The thread stack here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvpvlcsqjpqcxns/Screenshot%202015-11-16%2015.42.09.png?dl=0

Comment: Faulting is not the problem. That is how core data works, the word "fault" doesn't mean there is something wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304257/coredata-error-data-fault/7304350#7304350

Comment: The problem is probably inside your rather confusing dictionary-which-is-actually-an-array-of-tuples, but to be sure you need to add an exception breakpoint and find out on which line the unwrapping fails.

Comment: The error starts whenever I try to access an attribute for the second time. The printout of the Expense object is then like the second print statement. I know fault is just memory saving feature of core data. But for some reason it can't access its attributes anymore after accessing it the first time correctly. The object isn't modified in any way. I'll make the code a little more readable.

Comment: Do the exception breakpoint first

Comment: The exception breakpoint doesn't break any sooner then before. I will post the thread stack now.

Comment: How you have solved your problem ?

Comment: I used Realm instead. Cordata is/was really buggy

Answer (score 0):

Literally had this problem yesterday, how are you registering the customTableViewCell's class? If you have a reuse identifier on storyboard then delete the `tableView.registerClass()` line you may have included in view did load. Check your identity inspector and make sure your class on storyboard matches your custom class. Let me know how you are registering the cell.

Comment: I just use the reuse identifier. I don't have the tableView.registerClass since I think this overwrites the identifier. The identifier that I use to get my cell is correctly spelled. I added an update. It might have something to do with Core Data faults?

Comment: It should be something with your tableView, A cell is an optional but it should never be set to nil because its being reused by a previous cell on the table. You could also see if force unwrapping works for you using if let's.

Comment: The cell is never nil. its the Expenses object in the sortedStructure I created. The Expense object in expenseDictionary has a relationship that is nil. I can keep accessing the non relationship attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If objects resulting from fetch request are faults use

```
yourFetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
```

to disable them.

Comment: After implementing the results are the same. The first time I can access the fetched Expense and use it attributes. The second time I try to access them it give me a runtime error. (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)