# Core Data one-to-many insert with existing relationship swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

So I have a one-to-many Core Data structure

```
extension Category {
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var catHasExpenses: NSOrderedSet? }


extension Expenses {
@NSManaged var amount: NSNumber
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var expenseHasCat: Category }
```

When the app starts I insert all the categories. When I want to insert a new Expense it also insert a new Category, which I don't want. My insert Code:

```
func insertExpense(name: String?, amount: Double, date: NSDate, currentCat: Category) {

    // Fetch current cateogory
    let category: Category = self.fetchCurrentCategory(currentCat.name)!
    NSLog("\(category.name)") //I know I have the correct category here

    // Create new expense
    let expense = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Expenses", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Expenses
    expense.expName = name
    expense.amount = amount
    expense.date = date
    expense.expenseHasCat = category

    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        NSLog("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

func fetchCurrentCategory(selectedCat: String) -> Category? {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Category")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", selectedCat)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do{
        if let fetchResults = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Category] {
            return fetchResults[0]
        }
    }
    catch{
        NSLog("Error: \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

I know I create a new Category everytime I insert a new Expense because I fetch and count each entity at the start of my application.

- How can I just insert a new expense with an existing category?

Some more info:
[image: xcdatamodeld Expenses]
[image: xcdatamodeld Category]

Comment: please go through this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates

Comment: The code you have is not creating any new category objects, so the problem you're having is somewhere else. Are you sure you're doing the "insert all the categories" on startup properly, and not duplicating them there?

Comment: No I'm very sure it is only when I insert a new expense that a new category is created. I only create the categories when the entity.count = 0. I'm adding two photos about  my xcdatamodeld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does `Expenses` (which should probably be `Expense`) have a parent entity of `Category`? That implies some inheritance of attributes which you probably don't want, and also if you're relying on the count of `Category` entities, then all `Expenses` entities will also be included in the count.

Unless you really have a solid reason, you don't normally want to do entity inheritance in Core Data. All entities and inherited entities are stored in the same table in the database, which doesn't help performance at all.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem! It's my first time working with Core Data and I tried a lot of different things when I was troubleshooting. I apparently forgot to reset it to the original setting and overlooked it later on.

Comment: Maybe a little opportunistic, but I have another problem with Core Data that I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704370/faults-core-data-can-only-acces-object-once-when-working-with-uitableview