# how can I print core data right number?

Tags: ios, core-data

I set an Array to save the data from Core Data.

```
  var users:[Users] = []
```

when I want to delete one of my data from the tableView, I set this function, like this:

```
func deleteData(username:IndexPath){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        context.delete(users[username.row])
        print("test1")
        print(users[username.row])
        print(users)
        print(users.count)


        do {
            try context.save()
            print("test2")
            print(users[username.row])
            print(users)
            print(users.count)
        } catch  {
            print("Could'n save data")
        }
    }
```

I observed this operation, and I found some question here:

Below the context.save(), I entered the print (users), and the console comes out what the users data it is：

```
test2
<Users: 0x600000286770> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000e40000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p57> ; data: <fault>)
[<Users: 0x600000281ea0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000c40000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p49> ; data: {
    username = test1;
}), <Users: 0x6000002823f0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000c80000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p50> ; data: {
    username = test2;
}), <Users: 0x6000002823a0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000cc0000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p51> ; data: {
    username = test3;
}), <Users: 0x600000282350> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000d00000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p52> ; data: {
    username = test4;
}), <Users: 0x600000282300> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000d40000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p53> ; data: {
    username = test5;
}), <Users: 0x600000286770> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000e40000 <x-coredata://2D4CEBDA-C1B2-4CEC-A734-B7C9579C12A5/Users/p57> ; data: <fault>)]
6
```

but I just have 5 data, not 6. what's wrong with this problem?

Comment: If you are concerned that the final item in the array is showing as a fault, it is nothing to worry about.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7304350/3985749).  Faults are just CoreData conserving memory, the correct data will be silently filled as soon as you access any of the properties of the sixth item.

Answer (score 0):

Removing an item from Core Data doesn't automatically remove it from the data source array. You have to remove it explicitly:

```
context.delete(users[username.row])
users.remove(at: username.row)
```

Comment: thanks man, but why the console can't print test 6 , instead it print fault??? how can I print test 6 below context.save()

Comment: I really want to understand another question is : what is the  data : <fault> mean? Can I solve this code ?

Comment: I want to print test 6 not data : <fault>

Comment: You have deleted the record from the Core Data Stack. The reference in the data source array is still present in your code but the data are gone. To keep both data source array and the Core Data Stack in sync you have to remove the item also in the data source array as suggested in the answer.